# How can I resolve an ORA-12514 when connecting to an Amazon RDS instance using Java

Tags: java, oracle, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to my RDS instance using JDBC. When I attempt via code I get an:

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

error message. I am able to connect from SQL Developer with no issues using the same credentials, SID etc.

For those who have not used Amazon's RDS, it is a managed database offered on their AWS services. Because it is managed, I do not have access to the same facilities as a local install, and thus far have not figured out if or how I can access the `tnsnames.ora` file in order to get listener information.

My code is as follows:

```
public Connection connectToDatabase() {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//blahblahyadayada-eastnorthest-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/ORCL,username,password";
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url); // <-- error is here
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace(); 

            }
        }
        return null;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = db.connectToDatabase();
        try {
            ResultSet results = db.executeQuery("select 1;", conn);
            if (results.next()) {
                LOGGER.info("Results of query: {}",
                        String.valueOf(results.getInt(1)));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 ....
```

*EDIT*

Found the following listener information via the following statements:

```
show parameter db_name;
show parameter remote_listener;
show parameter listener_networks
show parameter local_listener;

NAME                                               TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
db_name                                            string      ORCL                                                                                                 

NAME                                               TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
remote_listener                                    string                                                                                                           

NAME                                               TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
listener_networks                                  string                                                                                                           

 NAME                                               TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
local_listener                                     string      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
```

The RDS parameters for the listeners are not modifiable and show as being Dynamic.

`select  * from DBA_SERVICES;` shows:

```
SERVICE_ID NAME                                                              NAME_HASH NETWORK_NAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     CREATION_DATE CREATION_DATE_HASH FAILOVER_METHOD                                                  FAILOVER_TYPE                                                    FAILOVER_RETRIES FAILOVER_DELAY MIN_CARDINALITY MAX_CARDINALITY GOAL         DTP ENABLED AQ_HA_NOTIFICATIONS CLB_GOAL EDITION                      
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------- ------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------- -------------- --------------- --------------- ------------ --- ------- ------------------- -------- ------------------------------
         1 SYS$BACKGROUND                                                    165959219                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  13-05-01                       0                                                                                                                                                                                                   NONE         N   NO      NO                  SHORT                                   
         2 SYS$USERS                                                        3427055676                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  13-05-01                       0                                                                                                                                                                                                   NONE         N   NO      NO                  SHORT                                   
         3 ORCL_A                                                           3453147048 ORCL_A
```

I modified my connection string to try `ORCL_A` with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC connection string is incorrect.

The string should be: `jdbc:oracle:thin:[user/password]@//<host><:port>/<service>`

Changing the connection string resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using any third party service like `AWS RDS`

```
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : mypw,  // mypw contains the hr schema password
    connectString : "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mymachine.example.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))"
  }
```